# React Native app built with fastlane - set ENV variables and load in JS code from process.env

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fastlane

I have different Fastlane lanes set up for the ios and android apps. I want to show some values in the app, e.g. latest build number (in test flight or google play), latest commit hash, changelog etc.

I am able to get it in lanes like:

```
previous_build_number = latest_testflight_build_number(
  app_identifier: app_identifier,
  api_key: api_key
)
build_number_int = previous_build_number + 1
commit = last_git_commit
commit_message = commit[:message]
commit_hash = commit[:abbreviated_commit_hash]
```

Then I thought it is possible to set these values to ENV and obtain it in the app:

```
ENV["BUILD_NUMBER"] = "#{build_number_int}"
ENV["COMMIT_HASH"] = "#{commit_hash}"
ENV["CHANGELOG"] = "[#{git_branch}] - #{commit_message}"
ENV["VERSION"] = "#{version}"
```

But when I am trying to get these variables set up with ENV["VARIABLE"] in my JavaScript code:

```
export const getAppVersion = () => process.env.VERSION || '';
export const getCommitHash = () => process.env.COMMIT_HASH || '';
export const getBuildVersionNumber = () => process.env.BUILD_NUMBER || '';
export const getChangelog = () => process.env.CHANGELOG || '';
```

The result for all of them is an empty string. Please, could you give me some advice?

Answer (score -1):

The [react-native-dotenv](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv) module can be used to accomplish that mission.
There is a good article on how to implement the module to an application:
https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-react-native-env-variables/

The steps must be taken:

1. Create (or move) the `fastlane` folder at the root level of your project instead of creating in `ios` and `android` folders.
   In this case, `./ios/` path must be added to `action` lines like `cocoapods(clean_install: true, podfile: "./ios/Podfile")`
2. Install react-native-dotenv executing one of the commands `npm install -D react-native-dotenv` and `yarn add -D react-native-dotenv`
3. Set the path of `.env` file using `fastlane` folder path

```
{
  plugins: [
    [
      "module:react-native-dotenv",
      {
        envName: "APP_ENV",
        moduleName: "@env",
        path: "fasltane/.env"  <-- set your env file path here
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```